# Wrap python decorator with another decorator

Tags: python, django, django-tests, django-cache

I have a common decorator call throughout my Django codebase:

```py
@override_settings(
    CACHES={
        **settings.CACHES,
        "default": generate_cache("default", dummy=False),
        "throttling": generate_cache("throttling", dummy=False),
    }
)
def test_something():
    ...
```

The decorator code is too verbose. I'd love to wrap this code into a new decorator called `@use_real_cache` so the test function looks much cleaner:

```py
@use_real_cache
def test_something():
    ...
```

How can I wrap a decorator with another decorator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just assign it to a value:

```
use_real_cache = override_settings(
    CACHES={
        **settings.CACHES,
        'default': generate_cache('default', dummy=False),
        'throttling': generate_cache('throttling', dummy=False),
    }
)

# …

@use_real_cache
def test_something():
    # …
    pass
```

This is essentially what happens in the first code sample of the question, except that you do not assign it to an (explicit) variable.